# Is it possible to remove duplicates in Dart with another variable

Tags: dart

I have searched a lot for removing duplicates from a list in Dart using ANOTHER variable.

Here is what I mean:

```dart
List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// This list has 4 new elements than the first one
List<int> moreNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

// Now I want to push the moreNumbers unique elements to the numbers one
```

I want to push it so the end result for the `numbers` variable should be:

```dart
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
void main() {
  var lst = [1,2,3,4];
  var lst2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
  var s = {...(lst+lst2)};
  print(s.toList());
}
```

Comment: No point in concatenating the lists!  Shorter to write `final s = {...list, ...lst2};`

Answer (score 1):

The trivial approach would be:

```dart
for (var number in moreNumbers) {
  if (!numbers.contains(number)) {
    numbers.add(number);
  }
}
```

Not particularly efficient if `numbers` is long, because `contains` on a list can take time proportional to the length of the list.

The time/space trade-off would be creating a set from `numbers`, because sets have cheap `contains`:

```dart
var alsoNumbers = numbers.toSet(); // Also linear, but only happens once.
for (var number in moreNumbers) {
  if (alsoNumbers.add(number)) { // true if elements was added
    numbers.add(number);
  }
}
```

(Using `add` instead of `contains` ensures that you update the set with new values, so you won't add the same new value twice.)

If you could just make `numbers` a `Set` to begin with, it would be much easier to avoid duplicates, just do `numbers.addAll(moreNumbers)`.